# Cant get HTACCESS to work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a question about HTACCESS and I hope you guys can help me with this! I'll explain the situation.

I have a hosting at antagonist.nl which is combined with the domain name zwarriors.net. I have purchased a domain name called joltblueprint.com (purely a domain name, so no hosting or whatsoever).

Provided I have the following situation:

I have a sub directory on my hosting with path: http://www.zwarriors.net/exampledirectory

I want to create the following situation:

Whenever people visit http://www.joltblueprint.com I want that URL to be redirected to my hosting, to the subdirectory of zwarriors.net/exampledirectory while maintaining and keeping the joltblueprint.com URL.

Is this possible? If so, how can achieve this?

Thank you for reading!

Regards,
Glenn

Comment: It is possibe, Please share what you have tried so far

Comment: Hi, thanks for anwsering. I tried the following:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?joltblueprint\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^forum/ /forum%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]

But that didnt work

Comment: Does you hosting plan allows more than one domain name?

Comment: .htaccess isn't really the right tool for the job; you'd be better off setting up the `<VirtualHost>` for joltblueprint.com in Apache's httpd-vhosts.conf file with the DocumentRoot that points to that */exampledirectory*. The nameservers will need configuring too ... but you may not have that level of access.

Comment: Can you share what will be your URL to redirect if user enters http://www.joltblueprint.com

Comment: They need to view joltblueprint.com/site but still have joltblueprint.com as their URL

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?joltblueprint.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/exampledirectory [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /exampledirectory/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Please, give some introduction and explanation to your answer, or it might be reported and deleted because of it's length and content. Thank you.